# can you help me identify my haro frame?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

[image][image]

Ive been searching on the internet and i could not find the name of this frame.

Comment: guessing HARO v3, circa early 2000's

Comment: @mattnz very astute of you to read the logo on the downtube and seat stay!  +1 for observation skills!

Comment: Might as well put that as an answer, @mattnz

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, looks like a Haro V3, probably early 2000's